# Не подключаются стили wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Не грузят стили wordpress, styles.css находится в assets/css/styles.css

выводится ошибка:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://bri/assets/css/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
bri/:82          GET http://bri/assets/img/home%20img.png 404 (Not Found)
bri/:88          GET http://bri/assets/img/speaking.png 404 (Not Found)
bri/:273          GET http://bri/assets/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
bri/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://bri/assets/js/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
bri/:102          GET http://bri/assets/img/writing.png 404 (Not Found)
bri/:114          GET http://bri/assets/img/reading.png 404 (Not Found)
bri/:136          GET http://bri/assets/img/listeting.png 404 (Not Found)
bri/:172          GET http://bri/assets/img/about%20img.svg 404 (Not Found)
bri/:180          GET http://bri/assets/img/pr1.svg 404 (Not Found)
bri/:195          GET http://bri/assets/img/pr2.svg 404 (Not Found)
bri/:210          GET http://bri/assets/img/pr3.svg 404 (Not Found)
bri/:228          GET http://bri/assets/img/contact.svg 404 (Not Found)
bri/:274          GET http://bri/assets/jquery/jquery-3.6.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
bri/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://bri/assets/jquery/jquery-3.6.1.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

```
<?
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style('css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/styles.css')
}) 
?>
```

В header.php и footer.php есть wp_head() и wp_footer();
Не понимаю в чем проблема, код вроде правильный, стили должны были подключится.
В index.php вырезал футер с хедером и написал get_head(), get_footer()

Comment: Для начала стоит задавать нормальные идентификаторы $handle (не `css`).

Comment: я начинающий, я не понял что за $handle и откуда он взялся. Можно подробнее?

Comment: Нужно читать документацию по используемым функциям https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: все понимаю, но я не зря обратился за ответом сюда чтоб на пальцах обьяснили что и как. Можно было ведь всего лишь дать ответ. Спасибо вам